# Transfer modules and Weyl algebra

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-operators, d-modules, weyl-algebra

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vectorial space of dimension $n$ and $V^*$ the complex dual space.

I would like to understand the following isomorphism $$D_{V^* \leftarrow V \times V^*} \overset{L}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{V \times V^*}} D_{V \times V^* \rightarrow V} \simeq D_{V \times V^*} \otimes det(V^*).$$ Here we use the standard notations for $D$-modules. In this case we work with Weyl algebras and $det(V^*)$ is the $n-th$ exterior product of $V^*$. The maps involved in the transfer modules are of course the projections.

Thank you for any help.

PS : This question has been asked on [mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691224/transfer-modules-and-weyl-algebra) without any answer but perhaps mathoverflow is more well suited for this.

Comment: What do you want to understand about it? From the definitions, $D_{V\times V^\ast} = O_{V^\ast} \boxtimes D_V$ and $D_{V^\ast \leftarrow V\times V^\ast} = O_V \boxtimes D_{V^\ast} \otimes det(V^\ast)$ (the determinant factor comes from the switch between left and right D-modules involved in forming the transfer bimodule). This seems to lead to the correct answer.